# Testing stateless, one-way message akka actors

Tags: scala, akka

In my project, we often use stateless actors. Reason is that we want to use these actors for fire-and-forget messages.

This provides us a quick way to perform an async task without creating and managing futures ourselves.

This works very well, but one of the issues is that testing this stuff is really hard. I wonder how can I write the test case for this.

One obvious thought is that at the end of the code execution I can do `sender ! EmptySuccess` and then the test cases could use the ask pattern to look whether they got the EmptySuccess or not.

The problem is that in production all the code will use `!` on the actor reference and therefore we may end up with lots of `dead letter messages` which may pollute our logs (because the senders don't really wait for receiving the answer from the actor).

Edit: We don't want to switch to futures as of now. Reason is that this is legacy code and if we cannot turtle our future all the way down, because this will mean a lot of code change.

Comment: Have you tried [Akka TestKit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html)?

Comment: It depends on the side effect your actor does. Usual pattern I see is that you check that the side effect was completed within a given timeout after you've sent the message to the actor.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is likely in the akka testkit.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html

If you just want to test that an actor is sending messages to another actor and that they are received, send messages to a test probe. You can then inspect that probe and do really useful things like ensure it received x number of messages in n seconds or use should matchers on the messages in the probe